# Кто нибудь может объяснить как работает коннет в PuTTY (windows)?

Tags: ssh, rsa, putty

Как PuTTY коннектится если он сохраняет только хэш в SshHostKeys, не используя known_hosts. На сколько я понимаю в SshHostKeys хранятся md5 от публичного ключа или какой-то другой хэш и он нужен только для проверки и предотвращения атак "man in the middle". Что тогда используется для получения ключа хоста или он уже где-то хранится? (ssh-keyscan работает значительно медленнее)